# creating a selected dhtmlXCombo

Tags: javascript, combobox, dhtmlx

I need to create a drop down list combo box using dhtmlx and populate it from a database with information instead of adding it in the code itself.

I can get as far as creating the dhtmlXCombo but it does not show up any information even if I put dummy text in to see and if the  it does it crashes the program the moment you click on it.

I have tried several different variations of creating the selection process and then tried to create a new combo section in the DHTMLx but still it shows nothing.

```
 //tDetailsGrid.cellById(0, 2).setValue('<select onchange="tbAddTrRegion "><option value="selTr" selected="selected">Cape Town</option></select>')//(this.option[this.selectedIndex].value);
           //tDetailsGrid.cellById(0, 2).setValue('<select id = "tbAddTrRegion"  onfocus="return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/><option></option><select/>');//<input id = "tbAddTrRegion" type="Text" value = "" onfocus = "return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/>
            // tDetailsGrid.cellById(0, 2).setValue('<selection id = "tbAddTrRegion" type="Text" value="" onfocus="return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/><option><select/>');//<input id = "tbAddTrRegion" type="Text" value = "" onfocus = "return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/>

//  tDetailsGrid.cellById(0, 2).setValue('<select onchange= "tbAddTrRegion" onfocus="return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/><option></option><select/>');//<input id = "tbAddTrRegion" type="Text" value = "" onfocus = "return checkTrEntryEditing();" style="width:100%"/>
```

I have currently commented them out at the moment but I only use one at time to find the suitable working one.

i then add:

```
TrRegion = new dhtmlXCombo('tbAddTrRegion', "Region", "100px");
            TrRegion.attachEvent("onselect", function () { this.select(); });
            $("#tbAddTrRegion").change(function () { region = $("#tbAddTrRegion option:selected").val(); });
```

I have created a somewhat a page method as I think that is the right way to go about doing it to get the info from the database per say but am not 100% sure.

```
PageMethods.GetTrRegionList(onGetTrRegionList);
```

this then goes to a function:

```
 function onGetTrRegionList(result)
    {
        var $tbAddTrRegion = $("#tbAddTrRegion");
    }
```

but at the moment the function is not connected to it at the moment because if the dummy values is not working then the function wont work either. The function would then send information to get the data back into the list so the user can select which ever one they would like.

Answer (score 0):

```
pls use the below code to add options to the combo    
var combo2=tDetailsGrid.getColumnCombo(2);
         combo2.readonly(true,true);
         combo2.addOption("selTr","Cape Town");
         combo2.addOption("selTr1","Cape Town1");
         combo2.setComboText("Cape Town");// for selected option
             combo2.setComboValue("selTr");
```